# NoneType Error while running a twitter sentiment analysis

Tags: python, tkinter, twitter, tweepy, google-api-client

I am trying to code a twitter sentiment analysis and I am getting a none type error on running it. I am not able to rectify it.

This is my code:

```
import re  
import tweepy 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from tweepy import OAuthHandler  
from textblob import TextBlob  
class TwitterClient(object):      
    def __init__(self):  
        consumer_key = '8WEgEeqZNxXL2D9h006Gv2k7U'     
        consumer_secret = 'SiCXmdiVvj5BSfWMG6Nven1bQyWt9S1Q0T7NkcbHXIj3oMkztR'         
        access_token_key = '3233710587-kc3RcYGIw0X3zteqObr4kcafxR16iViWyKSaWOH'         
        access_token_secret = 'xzmlIBZpVd2yZiWVjVEYttuOfuKOhtHiyjnB1bSfyz88n' 

        try:  
            self.auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)  
            self.auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)            
            self.api = tweepy.API(self.auth)        
        except:  
            print("Error: Authentication Failed")  
    def clean_tweet(self, tweet):  
        return ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Zaz \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", tweet).split())  
    def get_tweet_sentiment(self, tweet):  
        analysis = TextBlob(self.clean_tweet(tweet))       
        if analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0:  
            return 'positive'         
        elif analysis.sentiment.polarity == 0:  
            return 'neutral'         
        else:  
            return 'negative' 
    def get_tweets(self, query, count = 300):  
        tweets = []  
        try:  
            fetched_tweets = self.api.search_tweets(q = query, count = count)  
            for tweet in fetched_tweets:             
                parsed_tweet = {}  
                parsed_tweet['text'] = tweet.text   
                parsed_tweet['sentiment'] = self.get_tweet_sentiment(tweet.text)  
                if tweet.retweet_count > 0:                     
                    if parsed_tweet not in tweets:                    
                        tweets.append(parsed_tweet)               
                else:  
                    tweets.append(parsed_tweet)  
            return tweets  
        except tweepy.errors.TweepyException as e:   
           print("Error : " + str(e))  
def main():  
    api = TwitterClient()    
    tweets = api.get_tweets(query = 'elon musk bought twitter', count = 500)
    print(tweets)  
    ptweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets if tweet['sentiment'] == 'positive']
    print("Positive tweets percentage: {} %".format(100*len(ptweets)/len(tweets)))    
    ntweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets if tweet['sentiment'] == 'negative']   
    print("Negative tweets percentage: {} %".format(100*len(ntweets)/len(tweets)))    
    print("Neutral tweets percentage: {} %".format(100*(len(tweets) (len( ntweets )+len( ptweets)))/len(tweets)))  
    print("\n\nPositive tweets:")      
    for tweet in ptweets[:10]:         
        print(tweet['text'])  
    
    print("\n\nNegative tweets:")     
    for tweet in ntweets[:10]:       
        print(tweet['text']) 


if __name__ == "__main__":  
    main() 


from tkinter import * 
 
window = Tk() 
window.title("SE Project ") 
window.geometry('970x720') 

window.configure(bg='lightblue')

lb = Label(window, text="TWITTER SENTIMENT ANALYSIS")
lb.config(font=("Helvetica", 25)) 
# lbl.grid(column=0, row=0) 
lb.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)

lbl = Label(window, text="Enter Username:")
lbl.config(font=("Helvetica", 24)) 
# lbl.grid(column=0, row=0) 
lbl.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.49, anchor=CENTER)
txt = Entry(window,width=10,justify='center')
txt.config(font=("Helvetica", 25)) 
txt.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.55, anchor=CENTER) 
# txt.grid(column=1, row=0) 
def clicked(): 
    api = TwitterClient() 
    tweets = api.get_tweets(query = txt.get(), count = 300)    
    ptweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets if tweet['sentiment'] == 'positive']     
    res1=("Positive tweets percentage: {} %".format(100*len(ptweets)/len(tweets)))     
    ntweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets if tweet['sentiment'] == 'negative']     
    res2=("Negative tweets percentage: {} %".format(100*len(ntweets)/len(tweets)))     
    res3=("Neutral tweets percentage: {} %".format(100*(len(tweets) -(len( ntweets )+len( ptweets)))/len(tweets)))     
    lbl = Label(window, text=res1)     
    lbl.grid(column=0, row=1)     
    lbl = Label(window, text=res2)     
    lbl.grid(column=0, row=2)     
    lbl = Label(window, text=res3)     
    lbl.grid(column=0, row=3) 
    height = [len(ptweets),len(ntweets),(len(tweets)-(len(ptweets)+len(ntweets)))]     
    bars = ('Positive','Negative','Nuetral')     
    y_pos = np.arange(len(bars))     
    plt.bar(y_pos, height,color=['Pink','red','yellow'])     
    plt.xticks(y_pos, bars)     
    plt.show() 
    labels = 'Positive', 'Neutral', 'Negative'     
    sizes = [len(ptweets),(len(tweets)-(len(ptweets)+len(ntweets))),len(ntweets)]     
    explode = (0.1, 0, 0)  # only "explode" the 2nd slice (i.e. 'Positive Tweets')     
    fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots() 
    ax1.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%',shadow=True, startangle=90)     
    ax1.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle. 
    plt.show() 
 
    resp=("\n\nPositive tweets:")     
    lbl = Label(window, text=resp)     
    lbl.grid(column=0, row=4)     
    rew=4     
    for tweet in ptweets[:10]:         
        resn=(tweet['text'])         
        lbl = Label(window, text=resn)         
        rew+=1 
        lbl.grid(column=0, row=rew)
    resneg=("\n\nNegative tweets:")
    lb1= Label(window, text=resneg)
    rew+=1
    lbl.grid(column=0, row=rew)
    for tweet in ntweets[:10]:
        resn=(tweet['text'])
        lb1 = Label(window, text=resn)
        rew+=1
        lbl.grid(column=0, row=rew)
        

btn= Button(window,text="Submit", command=clicked)
btn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.62, anchor=CENTER)
btn.config(font=("Helvetica", 21)) 
# btn.grid(column=2, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

It shows error in the line:

```
ptweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets if tweet['sentiment'] == 'positive']  
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable.
```

I tried the above code and increasing the number of count values but it didn't work. I think I am getting the input from the field in a wrong way. I am using `get()` but I don't know if it is working or not.

Comment: This error is telling you that the list you're trying to iterate over, `tweets`, is None. Is `print(tweets)` printing anything?

Comment: no it's not. Do we need to get some permissions from twitter community?

Comment: I can't say, but chances are good is a problem with your tweepy API credentials.

Comment: These keys are working fine with the other code where I am manually taking the data and not from the user

Comment: Did you get any error in the console, like "Error: Authentication Failed" (when creating the api client) or "Error : ..." (when calling `api.get_tweets()`)?